# Azure data factory promotion from test to dev, authentication method is Managed identity for Azuressql,using azure devops CI/CD

Tags: github, azure-devops, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory, azure-managed-identity

I am using ADF and authentication method is Managedidentity -- then code is pushed to adf_publish 
    branch in Git hub and from there we are building the CI/CD in azure devops.

Problem - I used Managed identity for all the resources used in ADF like (keyvault,storage,azuresql) 
for Keyvault I am geeting this http url (https://BDAdhfsKV01.vault.azure.net/) this url we are 
paramterised in Azure devops release pipline (https://"$(vaultname)".vault.azure.net/) like this, 
but for Azure sql while using Managed identity I am getting blank in connection string after 
publishing to adf_publish branch to Git. How can be prameterised or promote to dev.

Just for refrence attaching the devops screen shot how I have paramterisded the keyvault URL at CD.
Same case blank connection string using Managed identity is with Azure synapse as well , Is there any 
help on this or any issue with Managed identity.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please refer to the document :  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-database#managed-identity to define your json file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to set the connection string as below:

```
"connectionString": "Server=tcp:<servername>.database.windows.net,1433;Database=<databasename>;Connection Timeout=30"
```

You can also refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-database#managed-identity).